# retrieve value from JSON file with duplicate keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

http://chriscargile.com/dictionary/tojson/moon.js

For example, I want to retrieve all the definitions of the word "moon" here. 
I have tried to use jQuery

```
$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    alert(json.definition)
})
```

This only returns me the last definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because duplicate keys are invalid in JSON. You need to create each `pos` and `definition` property in an object which is part of an array. If you paste your JSON file in to this [validator](http://jsonlint.com) you'll see why you only get one entry back.

A correct format would be something like this:

```
{
    "lemma": "moon",
    "definitions": [
        {
            "pos": "n",
            "definition": "the natural satellite of the Earth",
            "samples": [
                "the average distance to the Moon is 384,400 kilometers",
                "men first stepped on the moon in 1969"
            ]
        },
        {
            "pos": "n",
            "definition": "any object resembling a moon",
            "samples": [
                "he made a moon lamp that he used as a night light",
                "the clock had a moon that showed various phases"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can then use `$.each` (or even a plain `for` loop if you feel like going native) to iterate over each definition and its samples.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I kind of have to use that file because it is the only English dictionary JSON interface I find. I need to retrieve all definitions of a word in my javascript project.

Comment: In that case you would have to write your own parser, as it is not valid JSON I'm afraid.